# How to apply floor patch on underlayment for sheet vinyl

Tags: vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I am going to put down some new sheet vinyl in our bathroom.  I have put down [plywood underlayment](http://www.sureply.com) according to the instructions.  I am now trying to fill in the indents of the screw heads (#2 square) and a few places where I sunk the screws too deep.  I went to the local home improvement big box store explained to the staff what I was trying to do.  They recommended [this](http://www.menards.com/main/flooring-rugs/tile-stone/tile-installation-maintenance/tile-surface-preparation/tec-versapatch-latex-modified-floor-patch-leveler-327-25-lbs/p-2229963.htm) (tec versapatch latex modified floor patch and leveler).

This stuff was not what I was expecting.  I was expecting something smooth similar in consistency to drywall join compound.  Instead the floor patch is gritty, like mortar mixed with coarse sand.  I was not able to get a smooth surface no matter how I troweled the stuff around.

Did I get the correct material for filling in minor imperfections under vinyl?
Am I applying the floor patch incorrectly?

(edit: filling in screw head indents)

Comment: When you say *fill in screw heads (#2 square)*, do you mean the indent for the driver bit?  Do the instructions even call for filling in screw heads? It seems hard to imagine that the thinnest of sheet vinyl would deflect enough to show a screw head, even heads driven below the surface.

Comment: I have never used this stuff  but the description of the material makes it seem perfect for your application. It even says it can be troweled to a feather edge, I would think materials with a coarse aggregate could make no such claim. Are you sure it is still good; and that you mixed it up properly?